# Generating newlines instead of CRLFs in Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

For my unix/java friends I would like to send newlines ('\n') instead of a CRLF (
'\r\n') in Json.Net.  I tried setting a StreamWriter to use a newline without any success.

I think **Json.Net** code is using `Environment.NewLine` instead of calling `TextWriter.WriteNewLine()`.  Changing `Environment.NewLine` is not an option because I'm running as a server and the newline encoding is based on the request.

Is there **some other way** to force newline for crlf?

Here's my code -

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(writeStream, new UTF8Encoding(false))
{
     NewLine = "\n"
})
using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter) 
{ 
     CloseOutput = true, 
     Indentation = 2, 
     Formatting = Formatting.Indented 
})
{
       // serialise object to JSON
}
```

Comment: if the 'the newline encoding is based on the request.' - why isn't it set to LF for unix clients?

Comment: What about String.chr(13) + String.chr(10)?

Comment: @Isantipov, `Environment.NewLine` is a global (static) variable.  In a server I have multiple threads running; never mind `async` co-routines. I need a localised method of specifying the newline string.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne, thanks but I'm working in c# and not VB and I already know how to represent a CRLF as a string.

Comment: @RichardSchneider Apologies - trying to assist with a few shots in the dark.

Comment: @canon. Good question.  Its Formatted.Indented newlines.

Comment: @canon, because java friends (consumeres of the API) are complaining.

Comment: Among the API users, they have all requested XML and JSON be prettified to make life easier for debugging.  So accepted this on the provision that they accept GZIPed content.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After delving into the Json.Net code, I see the issue is with `JsonTextWriter.WriteIndent`, thanks **Athari**.

Instead of `_writer.Write(Environment.NewLine);` it should be `_writer.WriteLine();`.

I've posted a pull request to github. https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/pull/271

Answer (score 7):

If you want to customize indentation whitespace, just override `JsonTextWriter.WriteIndent`:

```
public class JsonTextWriterEx : JsonTextWriter
{
    public string NewLine { get; set; }

    public JsonTextWriterEx (TextWriter textWriter) : base(textWriter)
    {
        NewLine = Environment.NewLine;
    }

    protected override void WriteIndent ()
    {
        if (Formatting == Formatting.Indented) {
            WriteWhitespace(NewLine);
            int currentIndentCount = Top * Indentation;
            for (int i = 0; i < currentIndentCount; i++)
                WriteIndentSpace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Good solution.  But I was hopping for something where I didn't have to write code for Json.Net, but merely configure my serialiser. I really don't want to maintain code for another package.

Comment: @RichardSchneider Json.NET uses `Environment.NewLine` for formatting, so there's no other way. You can try suggesting this customization in the issue tracker.

Answer (score 6):

I see several solutions here that are configuring the serializer. But if you want quick and dirty, just replace the characters with what you want. After all, JSON is just a string.

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
json = json.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
```

Comment: Quick and dirty is right.  I'm looking solutions to configure the serialiser.  This solution has a performance penalty for the server which I'm not willing to accept. But thanks anway.

Comment: @RichardSchneider What make you think that it has a performance penalty. I would think that `SerializeObject` is much slower that `string.Replace`.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but I had a hard time getting the accepted answer to work and maintain proper indented formatting. As a plus, I am also not creating an override to make this work.

Here is how I got this to work correctly:

```
using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    writer.NewLine = "\r\n";
    var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        });

    serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
    // do something with the written string
}
```

I am assuming that the code [changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23588410/1784414) referenced in this question enabled the setting of `NewLine` on the `StringWriter` to be respected by the serializer.

Answer (score 1):

On the wire protocol for just about everthing is that a line ends with crlf.  If you feel that you really must do this, post processing is the way to go -- write it out to a string and then change the string before returning it.

Note that this is a lot of extra processing for what I would consider an actual negative.  Not recommended.

Comment: I agree HTTP is based on CRLF.  However, many tools that my friends are using can't grok a CRLF.  I'm just trying to make life easier for them.

Answer (score -6):

result = result.Replace(@"\r\n", "\n");

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: This answer doesn't need an added explanation. To be frank (my apologies), it should be deleted. It has not much effort put into it, and - more importantly - it is just duplicating an answer that has already been given about four years ago (stackoverflow.com/a/23588433/2819245) without adding anything of value (and as a bonus, it incorrectly uses a verbatim string literal). Looking at this, i can only think "_Why?_"